# JPA one-to-many join table with additional information

Tags: jpa, properties, one-to-many

I have these ER relations:

Person
ID_PERSON
NAME

Animal
ID_ANIMAL
NAME

Person_animal
ID_PERSON
ID_ANIMAL
DATE_OF_BUY

How to map the property DATE_OF_BUY in the association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is normally to map the join table to a relationship class.  i.e.

Person - OneToMany - AnimalOwnership - ManyToOne - Animal

See,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns

In JPA 2.0 you can also use a MapKey for some additional data, but this is normally more complex.